# How can I install pip requirements?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I am installing a requirements package list using

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

but I am getting the error

```
 Using cached alabaster-0.7.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
 Collecting anaconda-client==1.4.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
 Could not find a version that satisfies 
 the requirement anaconda-client==1.4.0 (from -r requirements.txt 
 (line 2)) (from versions: 1.1.1, 1.2.2)
 No matching distribution found for anaconda-client==1.4.0 
 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
```

What does this error mean and how can I solve it?

Comment: How does your requirements.txt look like?

Comment: You asks to install package version that does not exist on pypi.

Answer (score 1):

Pip is basically used to install the latest version of the files available on server
Pip install filename
Maybe the file you are installing is not on server till now